# Saving a complex structure to file in C++

Tags: c++, memory, save, ros

Although I'm using ROS, I think this is more of a C++ question.
I am creating an element of a complex class (`moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup::Plan`) and I want to save it to a file so I can load it and use it in other runs. Because its contents are not simply ints/floats/strings/etc. I cannot use the PicklingTools. I've seen the `Boost::serialization`, but since I did not define this structure I don't think I can use this.

Is there any way of doing this?

`moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup::Plan` has the following members:

```
double planning_time_
moveit_msgs::RobotState start_state_
moveit_msgs::RobotTrajectory trajectory_
```

Links to definitions:

- [moveit_msgs::RobotState](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/moveit_msgs/html/msg/RobotState.html)
- [moveit_msgs::RobotTrajectory](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/moveit_msgs/html/msg/RobotTrajectory.html)
- [moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup::Plan](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/structmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1MoveGroup_1_1Plan.html)

I tried doing it by simply writing:

```
template<class Archive>  
void serialize(Archive & ar, moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup::Plan & g, const unsigned int version){
    ar & g.planning_time_;
    ar & g.start_state_;
    ar & g.trajectory_;
}
} // namespace serialization
} // namespace boost
```

It compiles but that did not work. Also, I'm not sure how to actually save this to use it later. Would it save *all* instances of this class from now on?

Comment: Boost.Serialization can handle classes you didn't define. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#nonintrusiveversion.

Comment: @JoshKelley that won't work as OP's `move_group` class has `private` members 
 std::map<std::string, std::vector<double> > remembered_joint_values_` and `MoveGroupImpl *impl_`

Comment: Sorry, it's not `move_group` per say OP's trying to serialize, but `MoveGroup::Plan` which has all `public` members but two are defined in `moveit_msgs/RobotTrajectory.h` and `moveit_msgs/RobotState.h`.  Can you post them *and* `MoveGroup::Plan` in your OP please.

Comment: I have added that. Please take a look and see if that's what you were asking. Thank you

Comment: Ok, so I think I was able to serialize all those variables except for ros::Duration and ros::Time.Do you have any idea on how I can do that?

Comment: ros provides serialization for ros messages using ros::serialization.
You may be able to serialize and deserialize the moveit_msgs into a binary buffer using ros::serialize as show [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/11289/read-or-write-message-fromto-file/)
If this works, you can then use the ros serialized data and push them through boost::serialization along the `planning_time_` into a file.